# Popup A Modal containing Upload list on drop using blueimp jquery-file-upload

Tags: file-upload, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, blueimp

I've been using jQuery-File-Upload for months and have implemented a pretty sophisticated uploader with direct to S3, backend thumbnail post-processing etc.

However, I now have been tasked with allowing users to drop their photos on the main page and popup an embedded modal that will contain the file list.  Subsequently, the user will be able to drop more images on the modal itself. (using bootstrap modals)

I am using the jQuery-File-upload-ui with overrides.  I do not need to support non-HTML5 browsers. I am using Rails 3.1.11 and jQuery 1.7.2 with the jQuery-fileupload-rails 0.3.5 gem.

I have been working on this for a while and googled my fingers off in the process but cannot figure it out.

Is this possible?

Comment: I have the library working in a modal.  All is good... except!  I cannot figure out how to pass the filelist to the widget (defined in the modal) when the user drops outside the modal.  I think I want to define other .fileupload() objects with dropzones.  These zones would simply fill in the upload list in the modal and show the modal.  Subsequent drops would then be on the modal itself.

Comment: OK!  I answered my question.  Reading the doc at  

[https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/API] (for the 20th time) turned up this:  

`$('#fileupload').fileupload('add', {files: filesList});` 

But how to get the filesList??  For that I was happy to find this post by Craig Buckler:

[http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-file-drag-and-drop/]

I now have the modal popping up with the dropped files! (see next comment)

Comment: The function to pass the dropped file list to the modal and show it:

`// Call this guy when files are dropped
function FileSelectHandler(e) {
 // cancel event and hover styling
 FileDragHover(e);
 // fetch FileList object
 var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
 // process all File objects
  $('#new_upload').modal('show');
  $('#fileupload').fileupload('add', {files: files});
 for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
  ParseFile(f);
 }
}`

Comment: now I have the problem of my thumbnails getting moved around as the mouse hovers over, but that's another issue.

Comment: Share your generated html and css, will try to help you out :)